# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I work with arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, exc-bad-access

I always have error when working with arrays (non ARC code).

My code:

```
@implementation InfoController

NSMutableArray *lbCityArray;
NSMutableArray *lbTimeArray;
NSMutableArray *lbCameInArray;
NSMutableArray *lbCameOutArray;
NSMutableArray *lbInArray;
NSMutableArray *lbOutArray;
```

in ViewDidLoad I do something

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    lbCityArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    lbTimeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    lbCameInArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    lbCameOutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    lbInArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    lbOutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    //—add some values to arrays
    NSString *City = @"London";
    [lbCityArray addObject:City];
    //—————————————-----------------------//    

}
```

and always when I click Back button app crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. If I comment adding values to array all work, Back button don't crash app. I read if you use non ARC code you must manually release in dealloc.

I add to dealloc

```
[_InfoTableView release];
[lbCityArray release];
[lbTimeArray release];
[lbCameInArray release];
[lbCameOutArray release];
[lbInArray release];
[lbOutArray release];
[super dealloc];
```

and nothing changes, app still crash.  Where can be problem ?

Solution - I move to ARC and all problems gone. Thanks.

Comment: can you show crash log?

Comment: He don't write standard errors, on line 0x198f0b2:  movzwl 0xc(%edx), he write EXC_BAD_ACCESS and some address.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I can't be sure of what you're doing, but what is `_InfoTableView`? Did you instantiate it in a xib file? If you did, why are you releasing it?

Comment: Guys, I use wsdltoobjc and code generated by this tool not ARC ( _InfoTableView I use in this view, problem not in this TableView.

Answer (score 1):

It would help a lot if you made your variables into instance variables instead of global variables.

Change this:

```
@implementation InfoController

NSMutableArray *lbCityArray;
NSMutableArray *lbTimeArray;
NSMutableArray *lbCameInArray;
NSMutableArray *lbCameOutArray;
NSMutableArray *lbInArray;
NSMutableArray *lbOutArray;
```

into:

```
@implementation InfoController {
    NSMutableArray *lbCityArray;
    NSMutableArray *lbTimeArray;
    NSMutableArray *lbCameInArray;
    NSMutableArray *lbCameOutArray;
    NSMutableArray *lbInArray;
    NSMutableArray *lbOutArray;
}
```

Without the curly braces you are actually creating global variables, not instance variables.

Comment: I move to ARC and all problems gone. Thanks.